# WD40 on Single-Speed Chain

Tags: chain, single-speed

Simple Question: May I use WD40 to lubricate my single-speed chain? Does it not have any negative effects in terms of the chain performance and biking in general?

Comment: WD-40 is not a terrible substance to use for, eg, cleaning derailers, and it may be used to lube non-rotating parts (eg, a seat clamp), but should not be used for lubing rotating parts.  Use an appropriate (wet or dry) chain oil on the chain.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK WD40 would clean, but won't lubricate. And generally isn't really meant for bikes. Also one should be very careful with WD40 around wheel rims and breaks for obvious reasons.

As to the lubrication I've been told in a shop to use a lubricant after every ride (I live in Ireland, YMMV). Wipe the dirt, drop a drop of the lubricant on every link, wipe it again.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Just the assurance I need. I have been tempted to use WD40 on my chain. At least now I would stay off it.

Comment: Just remember to wipe off lubricant off the surface of the chain so that it doesn't collect more dirt.

Comment: Light oils displace heavy oils. WD40 is light enough that it would eventually evapourate, leaving your chain clean but dry.

Comment: "be very careful with WD40 around wheel rims and breaks for obvious reasons".  I keep an old cardboard amazon-ish box to use as a backdrop between the chain and the wheel.  My chain lube is in an aerosol can though.

Comment: Lubricate after _every_ ride? That's completely overkill for almost every rider.

Comment: Disclaimer: I live in Ireland where it rains every day :)

Comment: The WD40 debate. Like any lube, it has its limitations. If it's all you got, go for it. Wipe the chain down thoroughly and run the chain through an old towel after application and let dry as long as you can. Don't expect to get 200 miles between applications, as that is not what it does best. 20 mile ride, sure. Be prepared to re-lube every 2-3 rides. I've used in a pinch as an undergrad and had no problems. I now use Dumonde BCL or a paraffin wax bath. Mostly because I'm nerdy and they work very well.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the best chain lubes are:

- Teflon-based lube for dry conditions
- Silicon-based lube for wet-muddy conditions